# Change of Object in Server Is Not Reflected in Client

Tags: java, sockets

I have a `TestEllipse` object in my client class which extends `Ellipse2D.Double` that is sent to the server. The server calls its `updatePosition` method, wraps it in an ArrayList, and sends the ArrayList to the client. `updatePosition` adds 10 to the x-coordinate of the ellipse.

The strange thing is that even though `updatePosition` is called, when the client receives the ellipse in the ArrayList, the x-coordinate of its position doesn't seem to have changed. The updated position is shown in the server...

```
[TestEllipse[x=60,y=250]]
[TestEllipse[x=70,y=250]]
[TestEllipse[x=80,y=250]]
[TestEllipse[x=90,y=250]]
[TestEllipse[x=100,y=250]]
```

...but not in the client:

```
[TestEllipse[x=60,y=250]]
[TestEllipse[x=60,y=250]]
[TestEllipse[x=60,y=250]]
[TestEllipse[x=60,y=250]]
[TestEllipse[x=60,y=250]]
```

Why is this so, and how can I get the updated position to be shown in the client?

On the server side:

```
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            List<TestClient.TestEllipse> list = new ArrayList<TestClient.TestEllipse>();
            ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(31362);
            Socket socket = listener.accept();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            while (true) {
                try {
                    TestClient.TestEllipse e = (TestClient.TestEllipse) ois.readObject();
                    if (e != null)
                        list.add(e);
                    for (TestClient.TestEllipse ellipse : list)
                        ellipse.updatePosition();
                    // System.out.println(list);
                    oos.writeObject(list);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And on the client side:

```
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.*;

public class TestClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            List<TestEllipse> list = new ArrayList<TestEllipse>();
            TestEllipse t = new TestEllipse(50, 250);
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 31362);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            while (true) {
                try {
                    oos.writeObject(t);
                    t = null;
                    list = (List<TestEllipse>) ois.readObject();
                    // System.out.println(list);
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class TestEllipse extends Ellipse2D.Double {
        int x, y;

        public TestEllipse(int x, int y) {
            super(x,y,10,10);
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public void updatePosition() {
            x += 10;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "TestEllipse[x="+x+",y="+y+"]";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write the same object several times to a given ObjectOutputStream, the stream writes the object once, and then writes a reference to the object the subsequent times. That's what allows sending cyclic graphs of objects to an ObjectOutputStream.

To make sure the updated objects are sent instead of references, you need to call [reset()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset%28%29) on the stream.